# How to unify maps in Dart?

Tags: dart

Given any `Iterable<Map>` I would like to get a `Map` with the union of all the components of them in a `Set`.

e.g.:

> {"foo":1,"bar":1},{"bar":2},{"bar":1,"baz":1},{"bar":2,"foo":2}

should return a

> {"foo":{1,2},"bar":{1,2},"baz":{1}}

I just wrote the code, but the question is for available libraries in the SDK (or else in packages) that does this common task

```
Map unifyMaps(Iterable<Map> values) {
if (values.isEmpty) {
  return null;
} else if (values.length == 1) {
  return values.single;
} else {
  Map ret = {};
  values.forEach((m) {
    m.forEach((k, v) {
      if (ret[k] == null) {
        ret[k] = {v};
      } else {
        ret[k].add(v);
      }
    });
  });
  return ret;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you really want `unifyMaps({'foo': 1})` to return `{'foo': 1}` instead of `{'foo': {1}}`?  That seems inconsistent and seems like it'd be a pain for callers. (For example, why should that return something different than `unifyMaps({'foo': 1}, {'foo': 1})`?)

Comment: You're right. I won't remember why I added that else if, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

```
void main() {
  var inputs = [{"foo":1,"bar":1},{"bar":2},{"bar":1,"baz":1},{"bar":2,"foo":2}];
  print(inputs);
  print(unifyMaps(inputs));
}

Map<String, Set<T>> unifyMaps<T>(Iterable<Map<String, T>> source) {
  var result = <String, Set<T>>{};
  for (var entry in source.expand((m) => m.entries)) {
    result.putIfAbsent(entry.key, () => <T>{}).add(entry.value);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Or if you want to get a bit too fancy

```
Map<String, Set<T>> unifyMaps<T>(Iterable<Map<String, T>> source) =>
    source.expand((m) => m.entries).fold(
        <String, Set<T>>{},
        (result, entry) =>
            result..putIfAbsent(entry.key, () => <T>{}).add(entry.value));
```